Not able to add solana metadata using Metaplex
const { 
  Connection, 
  Keypair, 
  PublicKey, 
  Transaction, 
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} = require("@solana/web3.js");
const { 
  createMetadataAccountV3,
  PROGRAM_ID
} = require('@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata');
const fs = require('fs');

// Load wallet from file
const wallet = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('wallet.json', 'utf8'));
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(wallet));

// Create a Solana devnet connection
const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");

const mint = new PublicKey("");

const [metadataPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [Buffer.from('metadata'), PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer()],
  PROGRAM_ID
);

async function createMetadata() {
  try {
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      createMetadataAccountV3(
        {
          metadata: metadataPDA,
          mint: mint,
          mintAuthority: keypair.publicKey,
          payer: keypair.publicKey,
          updateAuthority: keypair.publicKey,
        },
        {
          createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
            data: {
              name: "",
              symbol: "",
              uri: "",
              sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
              creators: null,
              collection: null,
              uses: null
            },
            isMutable: true,
            collectionDetails: null
          }
        }
      )
    );

    const txhash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [keypair]);
    console.log(`Success! Check out your TX here: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txhash}?cluster=devnet`);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(`Oops, something went wrong: ${e}`);
    if (e.logs) {
      console.error('Transaction logs:', e.logs);
    }
  }
}

createMetadata();

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBuffer')

@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata is a UMI compatible library which is diferent from @solana/web3.js.
In this example, my advice is avoid combining those 2 and stick to@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata.
Try this:
import wallet from "wallet.json";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import {
  createMetadataAccountV3,
  CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts,
  CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs,
  DataV2Args,
  findMetadataPda,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import {
  createSignerFromKeypair,
  signerIdentity,
  publicKey,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import * as bs58 from "bs58";

// Define your Mint
const mint = publicKey("D5jhXjNR9RUZdCC4msRHEMHjSwHRUvuQQ7Ftb2WEz8pj");

// Create a UMI connection (e.g. to devnet)
const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com");
const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(wallet));
const signer = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, keypair);
umi.use(signerIdentity(createSignerFromKeypair(umi, keypair)));

(async () => {
  try {
    const metadata = findMetadataPda(umi, { mint });

    let accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
      metadata,
      mint,
      mintAuthority: signer,
    };

    let args: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs = {
      data: {
        name: "",
        symbol: "",
        uri: "",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        creators: null,
        collection: null,
        uses: null,
      },
      isMutable: true,
      collectionDetails: null,
    };

    let tx = createMetadataAccountV3(umi, {
      ...accounts,
      ...args,
    });

    let result = await tx.sendAndConfirm(umi);

    // Verify signature on https://explorer.solana.com
    console.log(bs58.encode(result.signature));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Oops, something went wrong: ${e}`);
  }
})();

Keep in mind you this is typescript and need to install extra packages such as:

@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults
@metaplex-foundation/umi


Thank you for the answer. I tried this but I'm getting this bug now:
TypeError: MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer is not a function.

I got carried away and forgot that @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata is actually UMI compatible and not @solana/web3.js. This is not a good answer.

I edited my answer to use @metaplex-foundation/umi which is the lib @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata relies on.

Thank you so much! This worked!

you can use this code :
const mintAddress = new PublicKey('insert here your publick key');
  
  const [pda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [
      Buffer.from('metadata'),
      new PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s').toBuffer(),
      new PublicKey(mintAddress).toBuffer()
    ],
    new PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s')
  )

Don't forget to add your public key

@Effe2
const { 
    Connection, 
    Keypair, 
    PublicKey, 
    Transaction, 
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  } = require("@solana/web3.js");
  const { 
    createMetadataAccountV3,
    MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
  } = require('@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata');
  const fs = require('fs');
  
  // Load wallet from file
  const wallet = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('wallet.json', 'utf8'));
  const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(wallet));
  
  // Create a Solana devnet connection
  const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");
  
  const mint = new PublicKey("D5jhXjNR9RUZdCC4msRHEMHjSwHRUvuQQ7Ftb2WEz8pj");
  
  const [metadataPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [
       Buffer.from('metadata'), 
       new PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s').toBuffer(),
       new PublicKey(mint).toBuffer()
    ],
    new PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s')
  );
  
  async function createMetadata() {
    try {
      const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        createMetadataAccountV3(
          {
            metadata: metadataPDA,
            mint: mint,
            mintAuthority: keypair.publicKey,
            payer: keypair.publicKey,
            updateAuthority: keypair.publicKey,
          },
          {
            createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
              data: {
                name: "",
                symbol: "",
                uri: "",
                sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
                creators: null,
                collection: null,
                uses: null
              },
              isMutable: true,
              collectionDetails: null
            }
          }
        )
      );
  
      const txhash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [keypair]);
      console.log(`Success! Check out your TX here: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txhash}?cluster=devnet`);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(`Oops, something went wrong: ${e}`);
      if (e.logs) {
        console.error('Transaction logs:', e.logs);
      }
    }
  }
  
  createMetadata();

But I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getPublicKey')
